# tk wm_grid err in wm_grid TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm grid window ?baseWidth baseHeight widthInc heightInc?"

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Whenever I run:

```
self.frames = {}
for F in (StartPage, Play):
    frame = F()
    self.frames[F] = frame
    frame.grid(0 , 0 , "nsew")
```

I get this error:

```
frame.grid(0 , 0 , "nsew")
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1674, in wm_grid
baseWidth, baseHeight, widthInc, heightInc))
TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm grid window ?baseWidth baseHeight     widthInc heightInc?"
```

What is the matter? I am Using `python27` and full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/rWu3XK3n).

Comment: It seems that you have a broken link to the sources ("here" is not clickable).

Comment: This is very vague. What is that `for F` then `F()` then `frames[F]` ? is `F` the only letter your government allows you to use to name variables, objects and classes?

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ: this code is a copy/paste from some other code; the OP didn't write this code. The name of the `F` variable is inconsequential in this context.

Comment: f stands for frame

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal example. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The code at the link you provided does not cause the error in the question. Please DO NOT link to external code. reduce your code down to the absolute fewest lines that generate the actual error, and include that code directly in your question.